# Progress bar mystery

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

It's like the old Sesame Street song, "One of these things isn't like the other."

I'm writing in WPF C# and I want to recycle some code I wrote a couple of years ago. In my old project I have a progress bar and here is what the properties look like:
[image]

In my new project I just added a progress bar (easy peasy) and I wanted to recycle my old code for changing the color of the bar based on value and some other stuff. But this is what the properties look like for this new progress bar:
[image]

So, what's going on? No MarqueeAnimationSpeed, no Step value (in the new progress bar)!?!? Also, it throws an error when I try to set the ForeColor.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for both projects. They're both WPF, C#. But, clearly these two progress bars are very different. I want the *new* progress bar to look and act like the *old* progress bar.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your "old" application is WinForms, not WPF - note the type `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a marquee progress bar in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638650/how-do-i-make-a-marquee-progress-bar-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` control in your old project is the WinForms variety. The `ProgressBar` control in your new project is the WPF kind.

You won't really be able to recycle your old code because the 2 platforms are very different.

Since you are using WPF you can create a ProgressBar in XAML like so:

```
<ProgressBar Width="201"
             Height="23"
             Maximum="100"/>
```

If you want a marquee effect you can set `IsIndeterminate="True"`

Or in C#:

```
ProgressBar progbar = new ProgressBar();
progbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
progbar.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
progbar.Width = 201;
progbar.Height = 23;
```

Comment: How do I change the color of the progressbar in WPF?

Comment: for example.. `Foreground="Red"` (XAML) or `Foreground = Brushes.Red` (C#)

Comment: Or you can use hex colours `Foreground="#FFFFFF"`

Comment: Thanks! You're really helping. One last question: how do I set the steps and the maximum number of steps for the bar? Ideally, I would like the bar to be 1-100.

Comment: Set the `Value` property to a double between your `Minimum` and `Maximum`

Comment: Again, many thanks! Sorry, but one last question. How do I set the color of the Progress bar in code from a method that returns strings like "Coral" or "Yellow"?

Comment: `SolidColorBrush redBrush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Red");`